# calculate field based on other field in select

Tags: php, mysql, calculated-field

Ok, I hope this time I ask my answer in a better way :) Sorry for the previous one.

I have this query:

```
SELECT getal,
    COUNT(*) AS aantalmaal,
    IF(aantalmaal > 99, 4,
    IF(aantalmaal > 66, 3,
    IF(aantalmaal > 33, 2, 1))) AS xkeerinzetten
FROM gevallengetallen
```

I get the error message: "#1054 - Unknown column 'aantalmaal' in 'field list'"

If anyone has an idea, thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't refer to an alias in the select list of the same query. Either do `COUNT(*)` in a subquery, or use `COUNT(*)` in the `IF` functions.

Comment: Also, use `CASE` for a multi-way condition, instead of nested `IF`.